# Calling a method of controller through javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

hello all I am new to mvc I want to call a method of a controller which is not an action method in a view through $.ajax but i am getting error in browser console .I want to ask that is it not possible to call a method which is not action method through ajax. code for view

---

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
}
<script type="text/javascript">



    function ajaxcall() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ValidatePin',
            type: 'Post',
            success: function (result) {

                alert(result.d);

            }


        })
    }
</script>
<h2>About</h2>
<p>
     Put content here.

<input type="button" onclick="ajaxcall()"  value="clickme" />


</p>
```

here is my code for method

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Services;
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
   [WebMethod]
        public static string ValidatePin()
        {
            return "returned from controller class";

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: MVC is a general term. If you want a general answer - sure it's possible.

Comment: If you want your code fixed, please post the code. A live demo of the issue would be nice as well.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you insist not to implement an action method instead of this static method?
my second question is what your method actully does? validation something? so how do you pass it to this method?

Think you might want something like this:

```
public JsonResult ValidatePin(string id) /*id=pin*/
{
    bool result;
    // do something
    return Json(new { IsValid = result, Message = "something" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}


$.ajax({
                url: '/validatepin/' + pin,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: json,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {

        alert(data.message + '  ' + data.IsValid);
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution with [incoding framework](https://incframework.codeplex.com/):

**Controller**

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ValidatePin()
    {
        return IncJson(new AlertVM(){Message = "Some thing"});
    }
```

**Razor page**

```
@(Html
  .When(JqueryBind.Click)
  .Do()
  .AjaxGet(Url.Action("ValidatePin","Pin"))
  .OnSuccess(dsl => dsl.Utilities.Window.Alert(Selector.Incoding.Data<AlertVM>(r=>r.Message)))
  .AsHtmlAttributes()
  .ToButton("clickme"))
```